# Usages of cores in Spark SQL Execution

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL queries and trying to understand it's working under the hood.

I have come across the term "Core" in the Spark vocabulary but still struggling to get a hold on the same.

I know that - `1 core = 1 task`.

My questions -

- Can anyone please explain what exactly does a `core` mean ?
- Does Spark UI show the number of `cores` currently allocated for my job ? If yes,
  then where can I see it ?
- If I find in the Spark UI that the number of `tasks` running is less, is
  there a way to increase the number of `cores` allocated for my job, so
  that Spark can submit more tasks and make my job run faster ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right in a way.
In spark task are distributed across executors, on each executor number of task running is equal to the number of cores on that executors. So basically core is something that is going to execute your task. The task here is the most granular work that needs to be carried out.

JOB=>STAGE=>TASK

Yes, spark UI shows you the number of the task currently running on your every executor. You can check them under the Executors tab. This tab shows you a very detailed view of your task allocation against the number of cores available and a lot of other details.

Yes, you can increase the number of cores. You can do that by passing the argument in the spark-submit command.

--executor-cores n
Here n is the number of cores you want. For optimum usage, it should be 5.

It is not necessary that more than the number of cores faster your job will run.
Your task needs to be distributed equally across all the cores available to run faster.
If you provide more cores than required they will remain idle most of the time.